# Match/extract all characters between 2 strings

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract John Doe from the string `\n*DRIVGo*\nVolledige naam: John Doe\nTelefoonnummer: 0612345678\nIP: 94.214.168.86\n`

So I guess the regex pattern needs to extract all characters between 'Volledige naam:' and '\n'. Is there anyone who can help me out?

Comment: What's the tool/language?

Comment: @JohnyL Sorry, forgot to mention PHP

Comment: @user3604531, don't forget to up vote and accept the answer which you found to be most helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex to capture the name in group 1,

```
naam:\s+([a-zA-Z ]+)
```

As the name can only contain alphabets and spaces hence use of `[a-zA-Z ]+` charset.

Php sample codes,

```
$str = "\n*DRIVGo*\nVolledige naam: John Doe\nTelefoonnummer: 0612345678\nIP: 94.214.168.86\n";
preg_match('/naam:\s+([a-zA-Z ]+)/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Prints,

```
John Doe
```

**[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rgjdj6/1)**

Comment: Answer is technically correct but only for valid input. Invalid input will either not be handled correctly or have unintended behaviour.

Comment: @Jay: You are right but as OP hasn't given any general rules or delimiter for text extraction, this is what maximum one can do.

Comment: Delimiter seems to be \n

Comment: You don't need to put `\n` as delimiter as `[a-zA-Z ]` character set will stop capturing text as soon as it sees `\n`

Comment: That's not the point, your logic potentially provides incorrect results [given malformed input] and does not allow one to handle characters outside of the range listed. The whitespace flag is a bigger problem than  your range as your use of it acknowledged different character sets however your range does not... hence you will match leading whitespace which does not even contain data required for parsing, that alone will lead to questionable memory usage and performance traits which are totally irrelevant to the problem at hand and [] introduced purely by your lack of understanding of automata.

Comment: @Jay: Like I said, had the OP provided more samples, I would have refined my regex further. I know capturing through set [a-zA-Z ] will also capture unnecessary white space and it could have been better written as `[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+])*` but even this wouldn't have been enough if the text following `naam:` had been a long list of alphabetic words and in that case I would have needed a better rule to capture the intended text. To summarize, giving the precise regex without enough sample text or rules, is like shooting in the dark. You can only aim perfect, when your target is precise.

Comment: My answer seem pretty precise, can be easily implemented anywhere and with none of the aforementioned negative charastics in which the other answers attribute. Now I wouldn't call it perfect but I would call it succinct, efficient and much easier to reason about in any circumstance conceivable.

Comment: @Jay: Well, your solution isn't any bad but it seems a bit too much for what OP wants. To me it appears as if you are trying to kill an ant with a bomb. Why write so many lines of code, when same thing can be done in just one or two lines of code? Your solution may be beneficial in case OP was interested in parsing the whole input to seek any of the information in the given input text. But given OP just wanted to capture a particular name, just gather hints and fetch the word using regex quickly and job done. I would not invest so many lines of code just to capture the name as needed by OP.

Comment: Your answer demonstrates so much that it's difficult to respond. What I will say is that you seem to regard lines of code vs applied performance in the completely wrong manner and that your analogies of ants and hammers is only applicable to your own answer given the understanding of what lines of code will be executed as a result of your regex, not to mention the implications to the application and system underlying.

Comment: @Jay: No, I didn't mean that lines of code is more important that performance/efficiency. But you can only hit your head hard in improving something or providing an efficient solution, once you know if that is the real bottle neck in a system. Otherwise, you may actually be putting real hard efforts in making something performant but in reality, it might barely improve anything because it might be almost nothing, compared to other bottle necks of the system/program. But I get your gist and do acknowledge it. But again like I said, unless you have a target, you can barely set your focus.

Comment: This has nothing to do with premature optimization IMHO and further I choose not to elaborate further on the subject as it seems you are set in your ways. Your target should be success via efficiency all other results are prototypically futile e.g. superficial

Comment: @Jay: I am open but I also account RvI (Return vs Investment). Defining something efficient sometimes depends on other factors. Because sometimes you may think something is efficient but in reality, you might be costing in another dimension. Sometimes it is wise to do quick and dirty work instead of slow and perfect work. Consider a person dying from thirst and was looking for some water to survive. But instead of giving a not so clean water, you asked him to wait and while you went ahead to cleanse the water, the person died of thirst. Your clean water is now useless as the person is no more.

Answer (score 0):

The required string exists constantly at `indexOf(':')` and ends at the same call using the previously obtained value of `indexOf` as the offset in the subsequent call. (Given that the first call doesn't indicate that the result was not found and also that result of the send call [which would indicate the complete segment is not contained in the string])

Using a regular expression for this seems less useful because the source string will not varry in some way which requires automata.

Consider a simple `split('\n')` operation [optionally given a length of matches to obtain] which can be followed by further such calls if necessary to obtain the desired value without the need of any underlying engine.

The logic provided would be the same as a Regex is doing for you with it's underlying implementation although the associated cost both in terms of memory and performance is usually only justified for certain scenarios [for instance involving code page or locale conversions but not limited to, another case would be finding words with incorrect Declension, Punctuation etc.] which in this case do not seem to be needed.

Consider a parser construct with fields and methods that can obtain [point to] and also verify the integrity of the data when requires; This will also allow you to quickly serialize and deserialize the results in most cases.

Finally since you indicated your language is PHP I figured I should also let you know that equivalent of `indexOf` is `strpos` and the following code will demonstrate various ways to solve this problem without the use of regex.

```
$str = "\n*DRIVGo*\nVolledige naam: John Doe\nTelefoonnummer: 0612345678\nIP: 94.214.168.86\n";
$search = chr(10);
$parts = explode($search, $str);
$partsCount = count($parts);
print_r($parts);
if($partsCount > 1) print($parts[1]); //*DRIVGo*

print('-----Same results via different methodology------');

$groupStart = 0;
$groupEnd = $groupStart; 
$max = strlen($str);

//While the groupEnd has not approached the length of str
while($groupEnd <= $max && 
      ($groupStart = strpos($str, $search, $groupStart)) >= 0 && // find search in str starting at groupStart, assign result to groupStart
      ($groupEnd = strpos($str, $search, $groupEnd + 1)) > $groupStart) // find search in str starting at groupEnd + 1, assign result to groupEnd
{   
    //Show the start, end, length and resulting substring
    print_r([$groupStart, $groupEnd, $groupEnd - $groupStart, substr($str, $groupStart, $groupEnd - $groupStart)]); 
    //advance the parsing
    $groupStart = $groupEnd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^Volledige naam:\s*\K.+
```

in `multiline` mode. That is

```
^                    # start of line
Volledige naam:\s*\K # Volledige naam:, whitespaces and "forget" what#s been matched
.+                   # rest of the line
```

---

In `PHP`:

```
<?php
$string = <<<DATA
*DRIVGo*
Volledige naam: John Doe
Telefoonnummer: 0612345678
IP: 94.214.168.86
DATA;

$regex = '~^Volledige naam:\s*\K.+~m';

if (preg_match($regex, $string, $match)) {
    print_r($match);
}
?>
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/re9uYD) as well as on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/qgSvwV/1/).

Comment: The . Is greedy and the use of such given arbitrary input could allow for unintended behavior such as but not limited to timeout and memory exhaustion.

Comment: @Jay: Why do you think so?

Comment: It's trivial to provide a large string to a system with varying non matching content with the intent of provisioning memory and cpu and also performing said input in parallel with no expected result other than system resource exhaustion. The Regex engine in question must have a timeout mechanism or built in heuristic to determine excessive matching which is caused by various factors, especially the greedy quatifier .

Comment: @Jay: Only half true. `PCRE` (which `PHP` uses) is vastly optimized. The greedy quantifier you seem to have problems with is only examined if the engine finds `Volledige naam:` before in that line. The expression itself is good enough for several Gigabytes.

Comment: Yea so several gb of Volledige naa♤ wouldn't match but would take a lot of time to parse with that expression especially when one inserts newlines.

Comment: @Jay: well yes, but rather hypothetical, don't you think?

Comment: Not at all since it resembles the output, a fuzzer would be used to generate data such as this which is sometime analogous to data corruption.

Comment: @Jay *several gb of Volledige naa♤ wouldn't match but would take a lot of time to parse with that expression* that's not because of the expression in the answer but because of that big size of input string. Even if that caret anchor wasn't there you could say something similar *especially when one inserts Vs*. The regex is well written so that it fails as soon as possible. There is no backtracking involved. So it's a linear search. But I suggest a dot-star in place of dot-plus for a possible earlier match.

Comment: How are you going to timeout your expression in a guaranteed amount of time yet continue where you left off when time expired using your example? How many operations and how much memory will your implementation use? Than finally what if you needed to port to a language without Regex or at least without pcre...

Comment: @Jay This is not a language agnostic question, nor is your own answer. So why the concern? However porting a regex is easier than porting a bunch of language specific codes since regular expressions almost share the same basic features and syntax and almost all high level programming languages provide a built in engine for it. As long as the regex complexity is O(n) there wouldn't be a risk to be concerned about a timeout and specially a timeout different than PHP timeout.

Comment: My answers is closer to agnostic than other supplied answers IMHO, this task does not warrant the use of automata. Easier in what way? Find me languages which implement preg_match as well while your at it... it's not that it's O n or not it's about the ability to adapt where the expression provided is not built in a manner which is appropriate for automata in general. You should be more concerned with how this will work with unexpected input rather than timeout anyhow since I'm sure you properly segmented before calling this logic anyway right...

Comment: @Jay Please do me a favour and tell what kind of input string on Jan's solution will lead to unexpected results. Without real concerns we shouldn't keep this up.

Comment: @Jan I still doubt.

Comment: @Jay I forgot to answer the very first question. Your answer is not even close to a language agnostic approach. Your idea is, although there is no must. Programming languages have their own engines or they implement an existing regex engine. They do not implement PHP's `preg_match` but they may implement PCRE - the engine. The above regex, even without a bit of modification is guaranteed to behave the same in Perl and Ruby and with a small change with almost all languages that implements a regex engine.

Comment: @revo, there's nothing left to say other than do as you will until you can't. All Regex does under the hood is use the same functions my answer does... good day

Comment: I didn't get any answer for what I asked.